# I want to get data from JavaScript with Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

There is price filtering written in JavaScript in the template. I want to take the price range given in this filter with dajngo and write a filtering function. I couldn't because I don't know JavaScript. How will I do?
So, i want to write a django function that takes the given start and end values and sorts the products accordingly.

main.js

```
  // PRICE SLIDER
 var slider = document.getElementById('price-slider');
 if (slider) {
   noUiSlider.create(slider, {
     start: [1, 100],
     connect: true,
     tooltips: [true, true],
     format: {
       to: function(value) {
         return value.toFixed(2) + '₼';
       },
       from: function(value) {
         return value
       }
     },
     range: {
       'min': 1,
       'max': 100
     }
   });
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `noUiSlider` but you would need to get the `from` and `to` values into Django - you can do that either by submitting a form when clicking `FILTER` or by sending an AJAX request. I presume you would just submit the form in a standard page submission as you aren't familiar with JS (and therefore AJAX).

```py
def your_view(request)
   filter_from = request.POST.get('slider_from')
   filter_to = request.POST.get('slider_to')

   YourModel.objects.filter(value__gte=filter_from, value__lte=filter_to)
   ...
```

You will need to replace `slider_from` and `slider_to` with the key values that are sent by the slider input in `request.POST` - this will be the name of the inputs themselves. You can wrap `request.POST` in a `print` statement to easily see what these are. It's just a matter of getting the values and passing them into the `filter()` function of your model.